# having a issue changing Kurento projects certificate?

Tags: maven, ubuntu, github, webrtc, kurento

I have configured the environment of **[kurento server][1]** (a WebRTC media server and a set of client APIs making simple the development of advanced video applications for WWW and smartphone platforms) and I got the tutorial project up and running.

But I am having an issue with changing the certificate that are included with the projects.

Can you please point me in the right direction on how to do that without causing a problem, since when I created a new keystore the maven compile failed.

-- here is a snapshot of the stack trace after doing what the site [ securing the application ] steps ( I double checked the password and certificate ) :

```
2017-07-16 10:35:43.508 ERROR 11944 --- [llRecApp.main()] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler [https-jsse-nio-8443]

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:103) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:81) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:244) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:874) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:969) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:233) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:178) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:297) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:145) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) [spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
    at org.kurento.tutorial.one2onecallrec.One2OneCallRecApp.main(One2OneCallRecApp.java:68) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293) [exec-maven-plugin-1.4.0.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:780) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:56) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(KeyStoreDelegator.java:224) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:70) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getStore(SSLUtilBase.java:136) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfigCertificate.getCertificateKeystore(SSLHostConfigCertificate.java:187) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.getKeyManagers(JSSEUtil.java:194) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:101) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(JavaKeyStore.java:778) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
```

**[1]: http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what_is_kurento.html**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an exact description of "the problem" or "the issue", it will be difficult to pinpoint what can help.

You can start by double-checking the content of "[Securing Kurento Applications](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/securing-kurento-applications.html?highlight=certificate)".
For instance, the command

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dkms.url=ws://kms_host:kms_port/kurento
```

would only work if your jar does include the new keystore in your jar file:

> File `keystore.jks` must be in the project’s root path, and a file named `application.properties` must exist in `src/main/resources/`, with the following content:
>
> ```
> server.port: 8443
> server.ssl.key-store: keystore.jks
> server.ssl.key-store-password: yourPassword
> server.ssl.keyStoreType: JKS
> server.ssl.keyAlias: yourKeyAlias
> ```

Double-check with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38477085/6309) which states:

> Check that you file is according to that, and make sure that you are providing the correct keystore location in `server.ssl.key-store`

Regarding the error message "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect", see "[keytool error Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16891182/6309)". It can be a passphrase issue for instance.

The [OP AhMaD AbUIeSa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3457355/ahmad-abuiesa) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125342/having-a-issue-changing-kurento-projects-certificate/45125922#comment77291410_45125922):

> After creating a new keystore from official site using the certificate and the private key the project worked with no problem.

---

As [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125342/having-a-issue-changing-kurento-projects-certificate/45125922#comment96095606_45125922) by [Nikola Lukic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1513187/nikola-lukic), to add a new certificat, you would need to :

- copy it into the container ([`docker container cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_cp/)) using the right path (a path valid from within the container, not the host),
- create a new image ([`docker container commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_commit/))
- run the new image as a new container: [`docker container run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/)

Comment: I added the stack trace after doing what the link above states

Comment: sorry it must be by mistake after dropping the stacktrace my mistake

Comment: @AhMaDAbUIeSa I have also added a reference to server.ssl.key-store

Comment: what I am trying to do is map the keystore with my official certificate that I already have on the site

Comment: I tried the solutions above but still there is a problem after changing the certificate I faced a problem that the project couldn't run

Comment: "the project couldn't run" You can edit your question with additional information

Comment: after creating a new keystore from official site using the certificate and the private key the project worked with no problem thanks for the effort

Comment: @AhMaDAbUIeSa Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I using  openvidu/openvidu-server-kms:latest i enter in shell of container . Know i wanna restart openvidu JAVA server and add cert ! How to do that ? How to find path for application.properties in docker container . With args my servers not working  ( docker run args ).

Comment: Is this variant with build from source ?

Comment: @NikolaLukic Almost 2 years later, I am not too sure, especially in a docker context. Could you ask a new separate question?

Comment: I resolved my problem it was wrong path i use path from host not from container , i copy cert jks intro container , create new image and run it ...

Comment: @NikolaLukic Thank you for your feedback. I have included your experience in the answer for more visibility.